# Combine 2 lists with condition in PowerShell?

Tags: list, powershell-5.0

```
$computerips = 'IP 1','IP 1','IP 3','IP 4'
$computername = "IP 1 NAME","IP 2 NAME","IP 3 NAME","IP 3 NAME"

For ($i=0; $i -lt $computerips.count; $i++) {
    $computerips[$i]+$computername[$i]
}
```

Lets assume that $computerips is a list of ip addresses and $computername is a list of ip address aliases / names.

How to include condition if else (Test-Connection) to above code based on true or false and use only name of ip address with status OK or NOK?

i.e I need to have something like this:

```
foreach ($computer in $computerips) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 3 -EA SilentlyContinue) {
        Write-Host $computername "Online"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host $computername "Offline"
    }
}
```

I need to somehow match name to IP before send it to output. Any help appreciate.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out myself...

Answer (score 0):

```
$computerips = '10.10.10.0','10.10.10.1','10.10.10.2'
$computername = "10.10.10.0 Server1","10.10.10.1 Server2","10.10.10.2 Server3"
foreach ($computer in $computerips) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 3 -EA SilentlyContinue) {
        write-host "$((($computername -match $computer).replace($computer,'')).trim()) Online"
    }
    else {
        write-host "$((($computername -match '$computer').replace('$computer','')).trim()) Offline"
    }
}
```

Output

Server1 Online
Server2 Offline
Server3 Online